# how to chain multiple observable reduce in angular 4 to generate base64 images

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I have multiple parent objects, each with multiple children, with each child with multiple links. I want to check all the children links, remove children that have no live links, and remove parents that have all their children removed.

I'm trying to do understand how to write the following code using Rx in angular 4:

```
parents.reduce((updatedParents, parent) => {
 parent.children = parent.children.reduce((updatedChildern, child) => {
   child.links = child.links.reduce((updatedLinks, link) => {  
     if (link is live) updatedLinks.push(link) // asnyc operation
     return updatedLinks;
   },[]);
   if (child.links.length) updatedChildren.push(child);
 },[]);
 if (parent.children.length) updatedParents.push(parent); 
},[])
```

I can imagine how to do this using promises, and promise all / promise.reduce etc with bluebird, but How would I go about implementing this using Observable and reduce etc? I am really confused by that and I don't know how to do it. I tried a few ways and couldn't get it to work. I want a single event to return to me the filtered results, just like a promise.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

This is the structure:

```
const parents = [
  {
    children: [
      {
        links: [
          'http://www.onelink.com', 'http://www.secondlink'
        ]
      },
      {
        links: [
          'http://www.threelink.com', 'http://www.fourlink'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    children: [
      {
        links: [
          'http://www.fivelink.com', 'http://www.sixlink'
        ]
      },
      {
        links: [
          'http://www.sevenlink.com', 'http://www.egihtlink'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

This is how far I go.

```
return Observable.from(parents)
      .flatMap(parent => Observable.from(parent.children)
        .flatMap(child => Observable.from(child.images)
          .reduce((updatedImages, imgSrc, idx) => {
            return this.http.get(imgSrc)
              .map(res => {
                if (res.status === 200) {
                  updatesImages.push(base64Ecode(imgSrc));
                }
                console.log(res);
                console.log(updatedImages);
                return updatedImages;
              });
          })
        .filter(p => p.length !== 0)
      )
      .filter(c => c.length !== 0)
```

Comment: updateLinks is the obervable? RXjs has a reduce operator but its used on the observable rather than sending the observable through an array reduce.

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. The input data is well-understood. What is the data transformation you are trying to achieve, and what are the possible desired side effects?

Comment: @Dory Zidon you mean you just want to perform async operations to all the links of the child (if there is any)?

Comment: added an example of what I'm trying to do..

Answer (score 0):

You could try using filter instead of reduce since reduce is more for squashing data rather than removing based on a filter.

There may be a better way to ping from angular rather than just grabbing the whole page but the idea is the same.

```js
const parents = [
  [
    [
      "http://www.onelink.com",
      "http://www.secondlink"
    ],
    [
      "http://www.threelink.com",
      "http://www.fourlink"
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      "http://www.fivelink.com', 'http://www.sixlink"
    ],
    [
      "http://www.sevenlink.com",
      "http://www.egihtlink"
    ]
  ]
];


function getLiveLinks() {
  parents.filter((child) => {
    return child.filter((link) => {
      console.log(link)
      http.get(link).toPromise().then((res)=>{
          live = res;
          //check if resolved and return if true
      });
      
    }).length > 0;
  });
}
```

Comment: The whole idea is to get it to work in an angular 4 project, without async await, those are new features not supported in many browsers...

Comment: @DoryZidon This can easily be replace with a promise, the main idea was to use filter instead of reduce.

Comment: Might I suggest you try a test. Looks like your `link` is actually the array of links.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite tricky, since the starting structure is not observable.
Seems to me it's best to resolve all the links first, then use a variant of your non-observable reduction.

```
// simulated http.get
const http = { get: link => Rx.Observable.of([link, link.endsWith('.com')])}     

// non-observable flatMap
const flatMap = (a, cb) => [].concat(...a.map(cb))
const links = flatMap(parents, x => flatMap(x.children, y => y.links))
console.log(links)

// Rx version of Promise.all()
const linkTests$  = Rx.Observable.forkJoin(links.map(link => http.get(link)))

linkTests$.subscribe(linkTests => {
  const isLive = link => linkTests.some(linkTest => linkTest[0] === link && !!linkTest[1])
  const liveLinks = links => links.filter(link => isLive(link))
  const liveChildren = children => children.filter(child => {
    child.links = liveLinks(child.links)
    return child.links.length
  })
  const liveParents = parents => parents.filter(parent => {
    parent.children = liveChildren(parent.children)
    return parent.children.length
  })

  console.log(liveParents(parents))  
})
```

Working example: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/YrjBMd)

Comment: Ya but then you have to re-run the whole thing twice..Ideally that's not needed somehow..

Comment: Twice? I don't understand.

Comment: If you mean the extraction of links followed by the scan of the tree are two loops, you'd hardly notice the difference since the main time cost are the http.get's.

Comment: Still, your example solution is more concise. I originally dismissed the idea of observifying each level of the tree, but the approach looks good.

Comment: After trying out the example solution (i.e creating observables for parent, child, images), I'm beginning to think it won't work, as ultimately it returns the images only, not a modified tree. Am wondering if it might work by adding side-effects into each level to modify the level, but it's starting to loose it's elegance.